# Laravel MySQL orderBy count

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, count, sql-order-by, eloquent

I'm using Laravel and MySQL, and I have a table *post* that represents post where users can comment on it, now I wanna order posts by the number of comments of each post in ascending/descending order, how do I do this in Laravel? I don't want to add a field in *post* table to keep track of the number of comments of each post, because updating that field manually each time a comment or a comment's comment is added/deleted drives me crazy...

This is how I create my *posts* table and *comments* table:

```
Schema::create('posts', function($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title', 100)->unique();
    $table->string('content', 2000);
    $table->timestamps();
});
Schema::create('comments', function($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('content', 2000);
    $table->unsignedInteger('post_id');
    $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->unsignedInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('comments')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And this is how I setup relationship between posts and comments in my Post model:

```
public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany('Comment', 'post_id');
}
```

And in Comment model:

```
public function post() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Post', 'post_id');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that as you showed but now you get all entries from database. If you will have 100 posts each with 100 comments, you will get 10000 rows from your database just to sort your posts (I assume you don't want to display those comments when sorting).

You could add to your Post model:

```
public function commentsCountRelation()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Comment')->selectRaw('post_id, count(*) as count')
        ->groupBy('post_id');
}

public function getCommentsCountAttribute()
{

    return $this->commentsCountRelation ?
        $this->commentsCountRelation->count : 0;
}
```

and now you could use:

```
$posts = Post::with('commentsCount')->get()->sortBy(function($post) {
    return $post->comments_count;
});
```

to sort ascending or

```
$posts = Post::with('commentsCount')->get()->sortBy(function($post) {
    return $post->comments_count;
}, SORT_REGULAR, true);
```

to sort descending.

By the way using `sortBy` and later `reverse` is not a good idea you should use parameters to sortBy as I showed

Comment: Thanks, may I add in your assumption, how would you paginate posts AFTER sorting them using ->paginate($perPage)?

Comment: @dulan That could be a problem but I'm not Eloquent expert. You could ask a new question, maybe someone else have another solution or know how to handle pagination in this case. The easiest solution would be adding counter column  as you said at the beginning and adding trigger to database to update this number but maybe there are also other solutions.

Comment: I'm using Laravel model events instead of database triggers, reason I say tracking the comments count manually is complicated is because I'm using onDelete('cascade'), so if a comment is deleted, all its child-comments got deleted, then I have to calculate how many child-comments that comment has, iteration, recursion and whatsoever. The model events only triggers once for the original comment that gets deleted, it doesn't trigger for cascade...

Comment: @dulan But I think using database trigger should solve the case but I haven't tested it so I'm not sure

Answer (score 1):

I think I've come up with a workaround:

```
$posts = Post::with('comments')->get()->sortBy(function($post) {
    return $post->comments->count();
});
```

This one order by the number of comments ascendingly, if you want to order by it descendingly, do this:

```
$posts = Post::with('comments')->get()->sortBy(function($post) {
    return $post->comments->count();
})->reverse();
```

Comment: This is awesome.  I was missing the () on my count, so I edited my comment.