# Laravel query - order by count

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to select all the users that have the type of *student* and count all the countries that are connected to them. The order should be based on the number of countries linked to them.

**Users table:**

```
id    name
1     user1
2     user2
3     user3
4     user4
5     user5
```

**Countries table:**

```
id     country_name
1      America
2      Australia
3      Argentina
4      Afghanistan
5      India
```

**pivot_countries_user table:**

```
id     user_id     country_id
1      1           1
2      1           2
3      2           1
4      3           1
5      4           2
6      5           2
7      4           3
8      1           4
```

**user_type table:**

```
id    type       user_id
1     student    1
2     student    2
3     teacher    3
4     lawyer     4
5     teacher    5
```

**Here's the laravel query that I tried:**

```
DB::table('users')
->leftjoin('pivot_countries_user','pivot_countries_user.user_id','=','users.id')
->leftjoin('countries','countries.id','=','pivot_countries_user.id')
->leftjoin('user_type','user_type.user_id','=','users.id')
->select('users.name','users.type',
  DB::raw('count(pivot_countries_user.country_id)')) // should be per user but I don't know how
```

**Expected output:**

```
name      type       total_countries
user1     student    3
user2     student    1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel MySQL orderBy count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375845/laravel-mysql-orderby-count)

Answer (score 2):

```
DB::table('users')
->leftJoin('pivot_countries_user','pivot_countries_user.user_id','=','users.id')
->leftJoin('countries','countries.id','=','pivot_countries_user.country_id')
->leftJoin('user_type', function ($join) {
            $join->on('user_type.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                 ->where('user_type.type', '=', 'student');
        })
->select('users.name','user_type.type',
  DB::raw('count(countries.country_id) AS total_countries'))
->groupBy('users.id')
->get();
```

then you will get expected result:
name   type         total_countries
user1   student       3
user2   student    1

Answer (score 0):

The following query generates your expected output.

## Query Builder:

```
\DB::table('users as u')
            ->leftJoin('pivot_countries_user as uc','uc.user_id','=','u.id')
            ->leftJoin('user_type as ut','ut.user_id','=','u.id')
            ->select([
                'u.name',
                'ut.type',
                \DB::raw('(SELECT count(*) FROM uc WHERE uc.user_id=u.id) as total_countries')])
            ->orderBy('total_countries','DESC');
```